# GPIOzero motor backward and forward pins

Tags: gpio, gpiozero

When creating a new motor object from the GPIOzero module like this: `import gpiozero`, then `motor1 = gpiozero.Motor()` you need to specify the backward and forward pins. What does that mean and what if the motor only has two pins?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the GPIO you are connecting to the motor driver board which in turn controls the motor.

The motor driver board normally has two pins per motor.  If you set one pin high, the other low, the motor turns clockwise, if you reverse the polarity the motor goes counter clockwise.

For the gpiozero documentation see https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/api_output.html#motor